# Java 8, stream filter, reflect, NoSuchMethodException

Tags: java, reflection, lambda, java-stream

I have this code

```
List<JComponent> myList = new ArrayList<>();
fillmyList(myList); //Some method filling the list
try{
    menuList.stream()
    .filter(m->m.getClass().getMethod("setFont", new Class[]{Font.class}) != null) //unreported exception NoSuchMethodException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
    .forEach(m -> m.setFont(someFont));
}
catch (NullPointerException |  NoSuchMethodException e) {} //exception NoSuchMethodException is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement
```

But, I have this error messages:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodException is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement
```

How solve this?

Comment: You need to catch it the body of the lambda function.

Comment: Please show me how to do that...

Comment: Your logic is flawed. `getMethod()` will never return null.

Comment: Note that getMethod never returns null, that all JComponents have a setFont() method since it's declared in JComponent, that NullPointerException should never, ever be caught, and the catch blocks should never, ever be empty: that just hides bugs and makes them very hard to diagnose. This code doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thank you, I'm working with JMenu, JPopupMenu, has items, and Separator....

Comment: So you’re working with `JMenu`, `JPopupMenu`, “has items”?!, and `Separator` and all of them are subclasses of `Component` and have a `public` `setFont(Font)` method. There is no need for Reflection here. Perhaps, your problem is connected to the actual type of `menuList`. You should include it in your question.

Comment: @JBNizet it took me a while to realize that this code is actually invoking the `setFont` method without Reflection in `.forEach(m -> m.setFont(someFont))` which makes the entire `filter` step even more nonsensical, as the compiler already states that the `setFont` method is always present for all stream elements…

Comment: @Holger indeed. Didn't notice that until I read your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not an exception but a compilation error.
You have to catch the lambda body that may throw the exception, not the whole stream.

Here is an example to return `false` in `filter()` for the element of the stream that has thrown the exception :

```
myList.stream()
      .filter(m -> {
          try {
              return m.getClass()
                      .getMethod("setFont", new Class[] { Font.class }) != null;
          } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException e) {
              // log the exception
              return false;
          }
      })
```

You may of course use a different strategy as throwing a RuntimeException and stopping the processing.

Comment: Mind that it’s not necessary to wrap `Font.class` with `new Class[] { Font.class }` as `getMethod` is a *varargs* method.